# Stuck on recursion

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, tuples

I'm trying to write a function that takes 2 parameters, an int and a list. I have to compare each element in the list with the int and store them in a tuple consisting of 2 lists, a list with numbers greater than and a list with numbers less than. I'm trying to do this recursively, but I don't know how to store the values so that they are not erased when I use recursion.

```
def greater_less(v:int,l:list):
    if l == []:
       return ([],[]) 
    elif l[0] > v:
       more = [l[0]] 
       return more + greater_less(v,l[1:])
    elif l[0] < v:
       less = [l[0]]
       return less + greater_less(v,l[1:])
```

problem is...when `l == []`, everything is cleared. Also when I call my function recursively, I believe everything before is also cleared

practicing recursion so a hint as to how to fix my issue with recursion would be great

Comment: Why recursion? Is it necessary that you must

Comment: How about if the element in the same as a

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23480348/divide-list-using-recursion).

Answer (score 4):

Let's write some code:

```
def greater_less(v, l):
    # First, are we in the base case?
    if not l:
        return [], []

    # Second, do the recursive step
    smaller, greater = greater_less(v, l[1:])

    # Now, we also have l[0] to insert into these lists.
    if l[0] < v:
        smaller.insert(0, l[0])
    elif l[0] > v:
        greater.insert(0, l[0])
    else:
        pass

    # Finally, return these lists
    return smaller, greater
```

Note that we store the returned lists from the recursive call, prepend to the correct one, and then return them.

---

Let's look at a run of this code. To make this a bit less repetitive, I'm going to labels the 4 sections of code in the function **A** through **D**. So **A** would be the base case check (`if not l...`) and **C** would be the `if l[0] < v ... else: pass` code.

```
main() calls greater_less(2, [1,2,3])
     A: We are not in the base case because l has 3 elements.
     B: Recursive call of greater_less(2, [2, 3])
         A: We are not in the base case because l has 2 elements.
         B: Recursive call of greater_less(2, [3])
              A: We are not in the base case because l has 1 element.
              B: Recursive call of greater_less(2, [])
                  A: We __are__ in the base case because l has 0 elements.
                     Therefore, we won't reach B, C, or D of this call.
                     We return [], [].
              B: Recursive call returns. We have smaller = [], greater = []
              C: l[0] is 3 which is greater than 2.
                 Therefore, we prepend onto greater.
              D: Return smaller = [], greater = [3]
         B: Caller returns. We have smaller = [], greater = [3]
         C: l[0] is 2, which is equal to 2.
            So we don't prepend this number to either list.
         D: return smaller = [], greater = [3]
     B: Caller returns. We have smaller = [], greater = [3]
     C: l[0] is 1, which is less than 2.
        So prepend to the smaller list.
     D: Return smaller = [1], greater = [3]
main's call to greater_less() now returns with ([1], [3])
```

Comment: I'm a bit lost as to why you did the recursive step before your if/elif/else

Comment: I'm not sure of a good way to explain this. To me, the above code is clearer than doing the calls within the conditional. Perhaps you should step through the recursive calls with a 2 element list.

Comment: so running through it the first time, we recursively call the function before we reach the conditionals. After recursively calling out function it returns smaller,greater, then we recursively call the function again, but how does the smaller,greater update itself instead of getting cleared each time we recursively call out function? Usually I see a __ + recursive call, but not here

Comment: I don't think you correctly walked through the function. I've attempted to include an example of doing this, where indentation represents recursion. Perhaps it will be helpful.

Comment: Almost got it. Do you know how I could reverse the order of the list in the tuple? By simply adding list.reverse() does not do what I want because we're constantly adding to the list when we recursively call the function. I've been trying to reverse the list order at the VERY END

Comment: The insert could insert to the end of the tuple instead of the front. Otherwise, you could make a function that prepares the data, and then calls the recursive function.